# How many try/except is too many in python function

Tags: python

I have a function that geocodes an address. I don't want this function to die so I am trying to catch the error and return a tuple instead.
However I also want to differentiate between errors, for this I use try/except in multiple places.

Is there such a thing as too many try/except? How would you optimize this function?

Here is my code:

```
def geocode(address):
    js = ''
    try:
        urlq = urllib.urlencode({'address':address, 'sensor':'false'})
    except Exception, e:
        return (False, "Error url-encoding address. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(GEO_URL + urlq)
        d = f.read()
    except Exception, e:
        return (False, "Error making connection. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
    #
    try:
        js = json.loads(d)
    except Exception, e:
        return (False, "Error converting JSON. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
    return (True, '', js, 'ok')
```

Comment: "I don't want this function to die so I am trying to catch the error and return a tuple instead" - don't be afraid to let exceptions propagate. It's frequently the right course of action.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right but in this case I am afraid :) because it is running from a cron job and I don't want it to stop from a bad address. So I just log the response if it's failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching `Exception` is always a bad idea. You want to specify which error you want to catch.

```
try:
    ...
except URLError, e:
    return (False, "Error making connection. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
except ValueError, e:
    return (False, "Error converting JSON. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
except UnicodeEncodeError, e:
    return (False, "Error unicode formatting. Error:%s" % e, js, 'failed')
```

Also returning a tuple to indicate an error is usually not preferred. Consider putting the try except in the calling function and to let the error propagate up.

Comment: Oh this makes sense. So I would have one try and use the except to catch the type of error. This will allow me to have the different error messages and reduce the num of try. Thanks.

Comment: You can add an extra `except Exception, e:` at the end to catch unexpected Exceptions.